# In Go, how do I create a "constructor" for a type with a string base type?

Tags: types, constructor, go

trying to have a type `Char` that is a `string` one character long.  what I'm unable to do is create a "constructor".  I know I'm missing something completely obvious.

declare the `Char` type

```
  type Char string
```

can use that type with a declaration

```
  var c1 Char("abc")
  var c2 Char = "abc"
```

these are wrong:  `c1` and `c2` need to be "a", not "abc"

what I really want is a "constructor" to limit Char to one character

```
 func Char( s string ) Char {
   var ch string = s[0]
   return ch
 }
```

of course having the `type Char` and `func Char` is not the way to do it

```
 type.go:8: Char redeclared in this block
```

is there any way for to force `type` initialization through a constructor?  or am I even asking the correct question?

let me state differently: if the user says `var c Char = "abc"` they will have an invalid value for type `Char` - is there any way to force the user into `func NewChar(string) Char` as `Char`'s only valid constructor?

Comment: It's the Go programming language, not golang.

Comment: sorry about the golang - thought I was seeing that as a standard ref. the difference between goggling for "go" vs "golang" is huge, so have always tried to put the phrase "golang" as a courtesy, but open to suggestions

Comment: If you want to force constructor, you should put your code in a separate package, expose public interface and a constructor that will return a private struct that implements the interface.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the `char` package. Note the unexported `Char` `struct` field `c`.

```
package char

type Char struct {
    c rune
}

func New(c rune) *Char {
    return &Char{c}
}

func (c *Char) Char() rune {
    return c.c
}

func (c *Char) String() string {
    return string(c.c)
}
```

Here's an example of how to use the `char` package.

```
package main

import (
    "char"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var c = char.New('z')
    var d = c.Char()
    hello := "Hello, world; or สวัสดีชาวโลก"
    h := []rune(hello)
    ก := char.New(h[len(h)-1])
    fmt.Println(c, "a-"+c.String(), '0' <= d && d <= '9', ก)
}
```

Output:

```
z a-z false ก
```

Comment: makes perfect sense (again).  with so many languages and conflicting paradigms it's sometimes difficult to get into the right zone.  still trying to wrap my mind around the whole interfaces.  cool, but need a quantumly better understanding before it becomes organic.

Comment: I get an error with this code: "cannot convert hello (type string) to type []int "

Comment: @RoboTamer use rune. It will work.
You will notice that because you have used *Char a big number in hex gets printed: like 0x7f2814d0af64 (it's memory adress)

Answer (score 2):

At the first, see following example.

```
package main

func main() {
    s := "hello 世界"
    //for getting characters from string

    cells := []int(s)
    for _, c := range cells {
        println(c, string(c))
        // You'll get
        // 104 h
        // 101 e
        // 108 l
        // 108 l
        // 111 o
        // 32  
        // 19990 世
        // 30028 界
    }

    bytes := []byte(s)
    for _, b := range bytes {
        println(b, string(b))
        // 104
        // 101
        // 108
        // 108
        // 111
        // 32
        // 228
        // 184
        // 150
        // 231
        // 149
        // 140
    }
}
```

The meaning of []int(s) is "cast to unicode characters".
The meaning of []byte(s) is "cast to bytes".

And, Go does not have constructor. In Go's style, package provide function NewXXX() for XXX object.

```
type Client struct {
    // ...
}

func NewClient() *Client {
    return &Client{/* ... */}
}
```

UPDATE:

If you mean Char as "1 element of string", you should define as following.

```
type Char int
```

Or

```
type Char byte
```

Your definition

```
type Char string
```

is re-define of "string". Then it can store string.

Comment: do not think I'm being very clear.  in `type Char string`, `string` is the basetype, so one can say `var c Char = "abc"`.  then `c == "abc"` but that's wrong - need `c == "a"`.  I guess what I am wondering is if it's possible to intercept and/or disable Go's initial interpretation of `var c Char = "abc"` === `c := Char("abc")`, or if there are other more sensible approaches to this problem.

Comment: thanks for the `func NewType() Type` Go style for a constructor

Comment: missed your original intent - thanks.  this is for a db interface, so (I think) `char` could be based on client encoding - a nasty problem I am cowardly ignoring for the time.  but I think you're more right than I am and will be moving `Char` to `uint`, so thanks for that.  do you have any ideas on the original question on how to keep the compiler from constructing types on its own and not going through the constructor?

Comment: No, I don't have any idea. go does not have constructor.

Comment: `Char("foo")` mean cast from string to Char. not a function call. If you want to create constructor(like) function, you should provide `func NewChar`.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the other answers, it should be noted that Go has no such thing as special constructor syntax. There are some conventions though. Generally when you have a custom type and need a constructor, you write a NewT() function which takes any parameters you need, performs initialization and returns one instance of said type.

```
type Char string

func NewChar(s string) Char {
    if len(s) == 0 {
       return Char("")
    }
    return Char(s[:1])
}
```

Comment: If a package t implements type T and there is only one constructor, the convention is to name it New so that it reads easily as t.New. For example: http://golang.org/search?q=New.

Answer (score 0):

A single unicode character in Go is represented by a uint32
You could do the following:

```
type Char uint32
var a Char = 'a'
```

No need for a constructor, since you can just use the character literal.

Comment: should have seen this coming.  let's say we want a `type Char2 string` where it will have exactly two characters, then how to solve the problem - or can it be solved?  btw, `string` for user sanity, since in practice a db `char` is mostly used as a string.